# Consulta MYSQL SELECT DISTINCT no funciona en MYSQL 5.7.21

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

En la anterior versión de MySQL del hosting esta sentencia me funcionaba sin problemas: `"SELECT DISTINCT Mes FROM recogida ORDER BY ID DESC"`

Donde la columna **ID** es código único para cada entrada de la tabla y Mes es el mes + año en texto, ejemplo "*Octubre 2018*". Los resultados los usos en un select option en HTLM para seleccionar los resultados de una columna **Mes** (que es mes más año) de la tabla **recogida**. El resultado me daba los campos únicos de **Mes** ordenados según el **ID** de forma descendente. Ahora con MySQL 5.7.21 ha dejado de funcionar.

El error es:

> 3065 - Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'c2034314_agua.recogida.ID' which is not in SELECT
>   list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Que quiere decir que ha dejado de funcionar? podes aclarar eso?

Comment: Que error te muestra?

Comment: Que da error de syntaxis en MySQL 5.7.21: `#3065 - Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'c2034314_agua.recogida.ID' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT`

Comment: @Multimedia pues es que ese es el error que debes colocar en tu pregunta para que los demás lo conozcamos, dale editar y escribelo ahi

Comment: Y agrega el Id al select. MySql tiene opciones que violan lo que es SQL ansi, y muy probablemente la version anterior tenia alguna de esas opciones prendidas.

Comment: Lo he probado, pero si agrego el ID al select no es el mismo resultado, la dupla seria por ejemplo "1 Octubre 2018", "2 Octubre 2018", etc y yo solo necesito el orden del ID, pero no el valor. Es decir, sólo necesito ordenador Mes por el orden que tiene ID

Comment: Algo me dice que esa tabla no esta bien... porque tenes esos valores? podrias mostrar la tabla y su contenido?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83965/discussion-on-question-by-multimedia-consulta-mysql-select-distinct-no-funciona).